# How to use "not in" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Try to figure out how to use "not in" in SQL.

I'm needing to find out the callers who have never made a call. Im doing this by linking the Caller_id from the Caller table to the Caller_id in the Issue table. I then tried to use "not in" to see if any of the Caller_id from Caller table have not appeared in the Issue table meaning they've never made a call.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdc47.jpg - How the tables link together

```
Select first_name, last_name
From Caller
JOIN Issue ON Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id 
WHERE Caller.Caller_id = Issue.Caller_id 
AND Caller.Caller_id not in Issue.Caller_id
```

My code doesnt return an output as its wrong but it should just display the first_name and last_name of the callers with 0 calls.

Comment: The WHERE condition has contradictory conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `NOT IN` with a subquery.  It doesn't do the right thing if *any* of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`.

Use either `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE`.  Your query is pretty far down that path, so you can easily do:

```
Select c.first_name, c.last_name
From Caller c left join
     Issue i
     on c.Caller_id = i.Caller_id 
where i.caller_id is null;
```

Comment: Could i also ask why you used a left join instead of a standard join? I dont really understand left/right joins.

Comment: What you refer to as a standard join is actually a short cut verbiage for "inner join" ; likewise "left join" is a short verbiage for "left outer join" , Inner joins return only those items matching the ON condition. Outer Joins will return the left (right) mentioned table even when the ON IS NOT MATCHED; null being supplied for all columns in the "missing table".  In this case Join would return only those callers that had made calls and Left Join returns those that made calls plus those that have not. The WHERE clause then eliminates those that have leaving the requested result.